can't activate wss on IIS production server with code running on IIS dev server
on a local IISExpress all runs fine:
I recieve:
{
    "negotiateVersion": 1,
    "connectionId": "****",
    "connectionToken": "****",
    "availableTransports": [
        {
            "transport": "WebSockets",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "LongPolling",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

which is followed by:

which means CORS is fine and, it seems, wss is activated.
On the production server, after activation wss for IIS, I recieve the same json followed by:

which seems to mean:

CORS is fine,
can't activate wss,
fail for ServerSentEvents,
OK for LongPolling.

My question is what may I do to have wss activatable on IIS ?
